# How do you remove illegal xml characters from mysql database

Tags: mysql, xml

I created a website with WordPress with about 5000 products. Now I am trying to list my products on an auction site in our country. I got a plugin to install, to pull our product feed from the site. The problem is that the feed keeps on failing because of an 0x3 invalid xml character error.

If I had to go through all the product descriptions to try and find the illegal characters, it'll take me forever.

It's a WordPress site with WooCommerce installed.

I know that most of the data gets stored on the database.

Is there a way to seek and destroy these illegal characters via phpmyadmin?

The table in question is wp_posts and the columns in question are post_excerpt, post_content and possibly post_title. The post type is 'product'

Comment: Are you restricted to using only phpMyAdmin to fix this?

Comment: I guess not. But it seems the only thing I have in cpanel is phpmyadmin. What is your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to make a second, identical table. Then select * from the original table into the new one while throwing out the invalid characters. Once the cleanup is done, truncate the original and restore the (clean) data.

Comment: that sounds like an option, but could you please help and post the commands here?